# Find the Maximum rows having all ones in the binary if you are allowed to toggle columns in the matrix for exactly k number of times

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, matrix

A binary matrix of nxm is given, you have to toggle any column k number of times so that you can get the maximum number of rows having all 1’s.

for eg, n=3, m=3,

```
        1 0 0

        1 0 1

        1 0 0
```

if k=2, then we will toggle column 2 and 3 once and we will get rows 1 and 3 with 1 1 1 and 1 1 1 i.e. all 1’s so answer is 2 as there are 2 rows with all 1’s.

if k=3, then we will toggle column 2 thrice and we will get row 2 with 1 1 1 i.e. all 1’s so answer is 1 as there is 1 row with all 1’s.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted. You may also want to check out [these hints](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284), or use the search engine of this site to find similar questions that were already answered.

Comment: Please credit the original source of the problem by adding a url or reference _in the question_.